# unable to copy div content into dojo contentpane dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dijit.layout

I am trying to create contentpane dynamilly using javascript and I want to copy the content of another div into this contentpane.

I used `.innerHTML` to copy the content but it is not copying the entire div contents. It is copying like a screen shot. Javascript functions and menus are not working properly. pls help.

```
//creating contentpane in javascript
    Tab = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                         id:"Tab",
                         title: "Tab",
                         content: document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML
                    });

    <div id="divID" style="display:none">   
    <div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton" id="menuId">
    <div>Add</div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.Menu">                     
    <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" label="add rows" ></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <table id="primaryTableId">     
    <thead id="invHeaderRow">
    <th id="Col1" class="col1">Col1</th>
    <th id="Col2" class="col2">Col2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="DataRow">
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use dojo query and
Replace content with content: `query('#divID')`

"content: document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML " change or display HTML text in the page but it does not responds to HTML content created by javascript ,dojo query takes care of that HTML content too

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: "content: document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML " change or display HTML text in the page but  it does not responds to HTML content created by javascript ,dojo query takes care of that HTML content too